# SSRS postback on date selection

Tags: reporting-services

I need to create report using reporting services in MSSQL 2008 R2
The report should have a lot of date parameters. The problem is that every time user selects a date via date picker reporting service performs a postback.
The parameters are not cascading and “Never refresh” is selected for all of them.

For a test I’ve created a report with simple MDX without any dates and with only one parameter (location).
I also added two dummy date parameters to the report. Parameter order is Date1, Date2, Location. 
Even in such a simple case I cannot stop reporting services showing “Loading” after date is selected.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new copy of the report on the server? Some parameter info is kept, even when you load a new report definition.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to create new report from the very beginning